# RestSharp Properties not Recognized

Tags: vb.net, restsharp

Using RestSharp (v105.1.0.0) for the first time. I'm using the RestSharp.Net4 dll and have added it as a reference. After converting the Getting Started sample from C# to VB I have the following:

```
Imports RestSharp
Public Class ClientOperations
    Public Sub invokeClient()
        Dim client = New RestClient()
        client.BaseUrl = New Uri("http://twitter.com")
        client.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password")

        Dim request = New RestRequest()
        request.Resource = "statuses/friends_timeline.xml"

        Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
    End Sub
End Class
```

There are now 3 error messages:

- 'BaseURL' is not a member of 'PROJECTNAME.RestClient'
- 'Authenticator' is not a member of 'PROJECTNAME.RestClient'
- 'Execute' is not a member of 'PROJECTNAME.RestClient'

A look thru the Object Browser shows that these are properties of RestClient

- Public Overridable Property BaseUrl As System.Uri
   Member of RestSharp.RestClient
- Public Property Authenticator As RestSharp.IAuthenticator
   Member of RestSharp.RestClient
- Public Overridable Function Execute(request As RestSharp.IRestRequest) As RestSharp.IRestResponse Member of RestSharp.RestClient

Have I done something wrong with the Reference addition that is RestSharp specific? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Asked and answered. I generated a class RestClient that conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered. I created a class RestClient to handle my local operations. facepalm